# Error while writing bootloader to SD card

Tags: boot, pi-4, bootloader

I have some problems with my RPi 4B, and one of the suggested tests is to overwrite a bootloader.

I'm trying to do this on my xUbuntu 20.04 with `rpi-imager`, but I get the following error:
[image: Screenshot stating "Error mounting FAT32 Partition"]

Tried two different SD cards, same result.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Is the card usable at all? The above implies it has some fundamental corruption or formatting issues.

Comment: yeah, I can write anything on it, even OS .img, everything except for this bootloader

Comment: Sorry, to clarify by "usable" I meant: *Does it currently work to run the pi?*  If not, I see an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479): Your actual problem is the card formatting needs to be fixed, eg., by re-flashing it with a fresh image.  If you don't want to do that because there is data on it you need, your problem is how to get that data off before you re-format it.  It may also be possible to fix it without losing anything (or much of), but that is harder.

Comment: This makes no sense. The imager writes complete images NOT partitions or files. It doesn't mount anything, except possibly at the end to verify.